# VBA/Macro to delete entire row with "only formula"

Tags: excel, vba, macros, formula

How can i delete all rows that only contain formula in Column A? I need to delete it so that i won't have problem in selecting range or when recording macro.

I tried:

```
 Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$L").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#REF!"
    Rows("720:720").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$719").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

and:

```
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("=+LEFT(#REF!,2)", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

but nothing works. I tried to delete all rows that has `#REF` or the formula itself `"=+LEFT(#REF!,2)"` but still no luck.

I need to delete all/entire rows that has only formula. These formulas are in `Column A`

Comment: use isformula() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the below code

```
Sub DeleteFormulaCells()
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If Range("A" & i).HasFormula() = True Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            lastrow = lastrow - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithFormulas()
ActiveSheet.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```